# Only one component is displaying from array of components

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-native-ios, vector-icons

I am using **react-native-vactor-icons** to draw rating stars and I am pushing each star in array and then display this array in render but only one star is being displayed.My code is

```
getStarsFromRating = (rating) => {
  let stars = []
  for(let i = 1; i<=5; i++) {
    let result = rating - i
    if(result >= 0){
      stars.push(<Icon name='md-star' size={20} style={[{top: 15, right: 15, position: 'absolute', backgroundColor: 'transparent'}]} key={i} color="#f57365" />)
    } else if(result < 0 && result > -1) {
      stars.push(<Icon name='md-star-half' size={20} style={[{top: 15, right: 15, position: 'absolute', backgroundColor: 'transparent'}]} key={i} color="#f57365" />)
    } else {
      stars.push(<Icon name='md-star-outline' size={20} style={[{top: 15, right: 15, position: 'absolute', backgroundColor: 'transparent'}]} key={i} color="#f57365" />)
    }
  }
  return stars
}
```

And in render function I am calling it like this

```
<View style={styles.rowBottomInternal}>
   <Text style={styles.restaurantName}>{item.get('name')}</Text>
   {getStarsFromRating(item.get('rating'))}
</View>
```

And my styles are:

```
rowBottomInternal: {flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems: 'center'},
restaurantName: { color: '#525257', fontSize: 24, fontFamily: 'MyriadPro-Regular' }
```

And I am getting something like this:

[image]

How can I display 5 stars here or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: All stars have same style `style={[{top: 15, right: 15, position: 'absolute'...`. It looks like they are overlapping. Check out in developer tools.

Comment: Sometimes minor details gives you a hard time. Yep Thanks that was the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be due to all of them having the position set to absolute. Can you see that all five components are loaded in the react devtools?